# Populating a List in a Strongly Typed LINQ to Entities Query

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am relatively new to `LINQ` and I'm simply trying to populate a List in a `LINQ to Entities` query.  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

The class "SearchCriteria" looks like this:

```
public class SearchCriteria
{
   public IList<DTOEventType1> eventTypes { get; set; }
   public IList<DTOLocation1> locs { get; set; }
   [DataType(DataType.Date)]
   [DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,
      DataFormatString="0:dd/MM/yyyy}")]
   public DateTime? searchDate { get; set; }
   public List<PortfolioLibraryMVC4V2.Domain.DTO.DTOCalendarEvents> 
      CalendarEvents;
}
```

and my query is shown below:

```
var query = from E in medRepo.evt
    join L in medRepo.loc on E.LocationID equals L.LocationID
    join ET in medRepo.evtType on E.EventTypeID equals    
               ET.EventTypeID 
    where IDsOfSelectedEventTypes.Contains(E.EventTypeID) &&
          IDsOfSelectedLocations.Contains(L.LocationID) && 
          E.EventStart > eventslocs.searchDate 

    select new SearchCriteria
    {
        CalendarEvents = query.Select(x => new DTOCalendarEvents
        {
            Name = ET.Name,
            EventStart = E.EventStart,
            EventEnd = E.EventEnd
            }).ToList()
        };

        var datalist = query.ToList();
```

I'm trying to populate the list "CalendarEvents" in the Class SearchCriteria in the select in the above query.  Currently, I get the error message "trying to use the local variable query before it is declared" so obviously my syntax isn't correct.  Can someone show me the proper way to do this?

Thanks,

Pete

Comment: Your question isn't very clear, and the broken syntax here doesn't help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give this is a try:

```
var query = from E in medRepo.evt
    join L in medRepo.loc on E.LocationID equals L.LocationID
    join ET in medRepo.evtType on E.EventTypeID equals    
               ET.EventTypeID 
    where IDsOfSelectedEventTypes.Contains(E.EventTypeID) &&
          IDsOfSelectedLocations.Contains(L.LocationID) && 
          E.EventStart > eventslocs.searchDate 
    select new DTOCalendarEvents
    {
            Name = ET.Name,
            EventStart = E.EventStart,
            EventEnd = E.EventEnd
    };

    var datalist = query.ToList();

var searchCriteria = new SearchCriteria();
searchCriteria.CalendarOfEvents = datalist;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take `SearchCriteria` outside of the linq query..

```
var searchCriteria = new SearchCriteria();

searchCriteria.CalendarEvents = (from E in medRepo.evt
                                 join L in medRepo.loc 
                                 on E.LocationID equals L.LocationID
                                 join ET in medRepo.evtType 
                                 on E.EventTypeID equals ET.EventTypeID 
                                 where                     
                                 IDsOfSelectedEventTypes.Contains(E.EventTypeID) 
                                 && IDsOfSelectedLocations.Contains(L.LocationID) 
                                 && E.EventStart > eventslocs.searchDate)
                                .Select(x => new DTOCalendarEvents
                                {
                                 Name = ET.Name,
                                 EventStart = E.EventStart,
                                 EventEnd = E.EventEnd
                                })
                               .ToList();
```

basically we only need the list of events from the LINQ query.

Comment: btw, Contains is a very tricky method to use in a LINQ query.. let us know if the above query solves your problem OR if you hit issues with Contains

Comment: Thanks Raja, jaredbaszler everything is working now . . .